# "Not Until" for future event

Tags: past-tense, sentence-structure, conditional-constructions, future-tense, learning

I read that sentences that begin with "Not Until" have the following structure.

> Not until [1st clause: subject + auxiliary verb...]  [2nd clause: auxiliary verb + subject...].

Of all examples I read, they are all events in the past, like

> Not until that evening was she able to recover her self-control.

which is synonymous with

> Until that evening, she was not able to recover her self-control.

So my question is, can we use "Not until" for an event that hasn't happened yet? For example,

> Not until she comes home will I have the dinner.

which in my opinion has the same meaning as

> I won't have the dinner until she comes home/ Until she comes home, I won't have the dinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. You can use the "Not until" structure for both future and present tenses:

> Not until she comes home will I have my dinner. [future event]
>
> Not until she comes home do I have my dinner. [present]

The latter sentence implies that she is coming home right now and that this is a habitual act (eating dinner when she comes home).

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned, it implies a habitual act. Something similar to: "Every day when she comes home I have my dinner."

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, since "not until" has the meaning of ["not before a particular time or event"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/until?q=not+until).